# How can I indent and bullet som paragraphs in a MULE description

Tags: format, mule, raml

I'm writing an API sepc using RAML and publishing using MULE standalone. I want to indent and bullet some parapgrach in the description of a Verb within a Resource. Is that possible? I tried using p style tags but it doesn't work, although using b tags for bold DOES work.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in RAML to put the bullet point in the description using `\n*` as  follows :-

```
/books: 

        displayName: Book
        description: !
                     "The following **services** that are listed here are :- \n\n* First point.
                     \n* Second point.
                     \n* Third point.
                     \n* Fourth point.
                     \n* Fith point.
                     \n* Sixth point.
                     \n* Seventh point  \n * Eight point with black bullet "

        get:
          description: !
                     "The following **services** description are :- \n\n* First point.
                     \n* Second point."
```

You need to have `!` and put the description under double quotes

Result you can see as follows :-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using the RAML Spec 1.0, and after some time I found out that line breaks work with `<br />`. So I added them and simulated bullet points.

Example:

```
description: Some fruits: <br />* Apple
<br />* Banana
<br />* Kiwi
```

This renders well then using `raml2html` to publish it.

I can see that this thread is quite old, but I still wanted to add it, if someone (like me) looks for a solution.